# Overriding a wordpress plugin for woocommerce button text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommmerce plugin that alters the text of the single add to cart button text.

The function in question does the following:

```
public function single_add_to_cart_text() {
    $price = $this->get_price();
    if ( $price ){
        $price       = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, wc_get_price_decimals(), wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), wc_get_price_thousand_separator() ), $price, wc_get_price_decimals(), wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), wc_get_price_thousand_separator() );
    }
    $text = sprintf(__( 'Participate now for <span class="atct-price" data-price="%s" data-id="%d">%s</span>', 'wc_lottery' ), $price, $this->get_id(), $price ? wc_price($price) : __('free', 'woocommerce'));
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text',$text, $this );
}
```

How can I update the text in my functions.php file? I need to override the returned $text value.

Comment: Hook into the same filter you see it applying there, and apply your own logic in your callback function …?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Put bellow code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function single_add_to_cart_text() {
    global $product;
    $price = $product->get_price();
    if ( $price ){
        $price       = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format(  $price, wc_get_price_decimals(), wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),  wc_get_price_thousand_separator() ), $price,  wc_get_price_decimals(), wc_get_price_decimal_separator(), wc_get_price_thousand_separator() );
    }
    $text = sprintf(__( 'Participate now for <span class="atct-price" data-price="%s"  data-id="%d">%s</span>', 'wc_lottery' ), $price, $product->get_id(), $price ?  wc_price($price) : __('free', 'woocommerce'));
    return $text;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'single_add_to_cart_text');
```

Comment: I get an error using this: 
UNCAUGHT ERROR: USING $THIS WHEN NOT IN OBJECT CONTEXT

Comment: I have updated the code! Please declare global $product inside single_add_to_cart_text function and use $product instead of $this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following snippet on your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'update_single_cart_text', 10, 1 );
function update_single_cart_text( $cart_text ) {
    $cart_text = 'your custom text here';
    return $cart_text ;
}
```